# update all UIViewController after language changed inside app

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, localization

I am wondering how to update viewControllers having nib files and UITableview as subview while i change language in setting page of my app not Device language. I could think of using NSNotificationCenter for this scenario, but at the same time i also need to think of updating table cell's label. I can't or am reluctant to reload the table because i am doing lot of things in cellForRowAtIndexPath method because the table is having lot of data.Again using delegate method is also a problem. Can any one suggest/help me how to root out this issue with out reloading table view.

Comment: search about localization... its built in buddy you need not to do any thing

Comment: thanks @amar for reply. I want language change in my app only not in device.So for that when user select language in app it should be reflected in all viewcontrollers and for this i am using NSNotificationCenter in all my ViewController classes.So that changes will happen immediate after language selection in app. So my question is how to tables cell name with out reloading table view.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi I did the same thing in my app put multiple language in plist then on the basis of a global variable fetch it from there. you can also define a macro LocalisedString(<pass key here>) use this every were.If you need code comment but will need some time.

Comment: thanks @amar. can you write code.

Comment: Given a answer take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom localization do this  (This answer is specific to this question not an alternative to localization)

make a macro in your defines file. if you dont already have one then

Add new file-> name it Defines.h -> delete its .m->delete every thing inside its .h->import it in .pch.

Now define a macro in it `LOCALISEDSTRING(m) [[[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Language" ofType:@"plist"]] objectAtIndex:globalIntIndex]objectForKey:m]`

you "globalIntIndex" is also declared in defines.h set it with the appropriate indexvalue for each language.

Now add a plist file and name it "Language" add in it your languages as array element and inside each language add KEY with string value as dictionary. Key will be same for each language

[image]

Plist will look like above image put all English text in item 0 and Russian text in item 1.

now you can use  it like `NSLog(@"%@",LOCALISEDSTRING(@"KEY"));`
if globalIntIndex=0 then it will print string in english else it will print string in russian.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,its working.Now my doubt is like, Suppose there are three ViewControllers named A,B,C. In C ViewController there is an option to change languge,and after changing it, all UI parts like label,textField,button,table's cell text need to be changed in all three ViewController.If i am implementing as per your idea it is not updating.

Comment: You need to set the text in view will appear method.

Comment: This is the issue because i am having lot of data in table view,so if i reload table view for updating tableView performance issue will come to front.So other way to update..

Comment: If you are changing language the you will have to re load. if your language change option and table view are not in same view then i think you can do a reload in viewwillappear try lazy loading etc for improved tabelview performance

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be no `Localizable.strings` file in your app.
Learn about this tutorial : [Localization Tutorial for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios).

In addition, here are two demo:
If you use XIB to build UI, see [RMDateSelectionViewController](https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController)
If you use code to build UI, see [ZCImagePickerController](https://github.com/VincentSit/ZCImagePickerController)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your present language instantly, you should implement multiple language on your own code. Normally a class to handle all string displayed with your interface. A notification to handle language change is recommend for each controller.

You can use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil]
         forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

to set your present language, but its may not change instantly and also not recommended.

Comment: Language change is happening based on language selection in my app,my doubt is how to change table view's cell name with out calling cellForRowAtIndexPath  method and all UI parts. I am using NSSNotificationCenter for updating ViewControllers.

Comment: @Amit89 notification is not recommended it is adding additional code use a macro where ever you will use the notification i have given a sample in my answer ask if not clear.